# SQL Server database tables are not visible in VS 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application. In VS 2013 Server Explorer, I've created a connection using the SQL Server type connector with a reference to the SQL Server service name as the "server name." The "Test Connection" button shows that the connection is successful. However, in the Server Explorer, when I go to expand the tables, no tables are shown.

Looking forward for the help.

Thanks,
NAd

Answer (score 0):

right click Change View to user objects